# How do I use the VS Code Debugger with an ExpressJS server compiled with Webpack?

Tags: node.js, debugging, webpack, compilation

I have been struggling to debug my server side code that is compiled with webpack.  I am using VS Code which has a great built in debugger which would be amazing to connect to.  My webpack config is pasted bellow.  I have tried many of the techniques mentioned in the posts here on stackoverflow but I seem to only find solutions for dev servers used for frontend frameworks like vuejs or a create-react-app server.  **This is for an expressjs server.**

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

serverConfig = {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/server/index.js'],
    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    output: {
      path: __dirname,
      filename: 'server.js',
      publicPath: '/'
    },
    optimization: {
      minimize: true
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        { test: /\.(js)$/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: 'babel-loader' }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        __isBrowser__: "false"
      })
    ]
  }
```

I have already tried this:
**npm-script for debugger**

```
    "debug": "node --inspect--brk=9229 server.js"
```

With the VS code debugger script (and variations of it)

```
    {
        "name": "Launch via NPM",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "run-script", "debug"
        ],
        "port": 9229
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated! I've been missing out on debugging and getting very tired of console logs.  Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same issue while trying to hookup VS Code debugger with many trials without success. As the code is transpiled, Im not sure which other config settings should be applied here :(

Comment: Let me know if you find anything!  I'll post a solution here when I find one